# Ambiguous terminology in a REST interface parameter specification?

Tags: c#, rest, wcf, sharepoint

**Context:**

Given a REST service specification. The service operations will serve SharePoint data to external systems. Before asking the creator of the spec. to made some clarification, I would like to sure I did not miss any trivial convention...

**Question:**

How to interpret this parameter specification?

> **Parameters:** PartNumber *, SerialNumber(n) *, CategoryNumber (optional search term), Description (optional search term)

**My thoughts so far:**

First I thought the '*' means that the parameter is optional, with the meaning 'all'. This is correlates with C# WCF convention of optional REST path parameter and also correlates with SharePoint search convention (where * means: all)

However the interface specification uses '(optional search term)' for CategoryNumber, so I am supposing the '*' could not mean the very same...

Also: What could be the meaning the '(n)' in 'SerialNumber(n) *'?

Answer (score 1):

> Given a REST service specification

According to the Oxford English Dictionary, the [definition](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/specification) of the word *specification* is:

> An act of identifying something precisely or of stating a precise
>   requirement

I don't think this qualifies.

Are these parameters path, request body, query string, or a combination thereof?

It's a highly unorthodox method of documentation and basically impossible to interpret.

Rather than producing such ambiguity, the API provider should be using one of the standard API specification formats, such as [OpenAPI](http://swagger.io/) (swagger), [RAML](https://github.com/raml-org/raml-spec), or [API Blueprint](https://apiblueprint.org/).

Faced with your situation, I would entirely not worry about asking for clarification.

In fact, I would tell the API provider that this level of documentation is wholly unsatisfactory.

> By default I suppose path parameters where it is possible

Okay, my best guess would be:

These are all body parameters. The POST request payload would be something like:

```
{
    "PartNumber":"*",
    "SerialNumber":"6786,9879,8979"
}
```

The reason for this -

I assume that all the parameters are of the same type. If this is true, then the two optional parameters lead me to the conclusion that they must be body parameters, since that's how optional parameters are typically modelled.

The *'s are therefore just wildcard query terms.

The (n) is just a clunky way of indicating that multiple Serial Number values are permitted.

The thing is, I'm entirely wrong, so go get clarification.

Comment: Agree. By default I suppose path parameters where it is possible. The question of "path, request body or query string" is not defined. The quote is from a textual specification

Comment: Many thanks for the answer. My only concern is that it is a GetXxx like operation, so POST seems to be not appropriate...

Comment: @g.pickardou - as I said, it's highly ambiguous and leaves you no option but to seek clarification.